# sql server make view that converts from and to datetime columns into a binary column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 5 columns:

```
UTC date NON NULL,
ID int NON NULL,
event1_start datetime NULL,
event1_end datetime NULL,
event2_start datetime NULL,
event2_end datetime NULL
```

It looks like this:

[image]

For machine learning and other tasks I want to create a view in the database that turns this into a timeseries with a stepsize of 15 minutes with 1 column per event in binary format indicating if the datetime falls between the event's start and end datetime values.

I have no idea where to start but conceptually it is pretty simple. It might be important to note that the actual table contains 6 million records, start & end columns for ~10 events and ~ 600 ID's.

example:

```
UTC_datetime,        ID,  event1, event2
2021-07-01 00:00:00, 31,       0,      0
2021-07-01 00:15:00, 31,       0,      0
.
.
2021-07-01 12:00:00, 31,       1,      1
2021-07-01 12:15:00, 31,       1,      1
```

Comment: Posting your sample data in a consumable format (ideally DDL and DML statements) would be a good start here. Images of data isn't helpful to us, as we can't use it.

Comment: If at all possible I would start by normalizing your table structure. Event1_start, Event2_start etc means you have violated 1NF with what is known as "repeating groups". It is really painful to work with and constrains your business logic needlessly. Consider how difficult it would be to add an 11th. It would mean touching every single query against this table.

Comment: @Larnu I'm not sure how to do that short of manually writing it out, i am looking into it.

Comment: @SeanLange I see what you mean, It would probably be much more efficient if i had an "event" column, a "start_dt" and "end_dt" column? Or do you have a different suggestion?

Comment: Seems to be a small matter of a CROSS JOIN for the time increments. but it is not clear if a record can span dates   i.e.  start 2021-07-01 23:45:00  end 2021-07-02 01:25:00

Comment: That is pretty much exactly what I mean. It would mean more rows but each row would be a single unit of information.

Comment: @SeanLange Great, I have to stop working on this for today, i will change my table tomorrow to the proposed format and find a way to export a sample. Then I will update my question and replace the image of my table :P

Comment: Instead of posting an image it would be far more helpful if you posted it as a create table statement followed by some insert statements. That way others can work with your data and help you find a solution easily. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=Images%20are%20harder%20to%20read,actual%20code%20and%20formatting%20it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using an ad-hoc tally/numbers table in a `CROSS JOIN` augmented by a `CROSS APPLY`

**Example**

```
Select UTC_Datetime
      ,ID
      ,Event1 = case when UTC_Datetime between event1_start and event1_end then 1 else 0 end
      ,Event2 = case when UTC_Datetime between event2_start and event2_end then 1 else 0 end
 From YourTable A
 Cross Join  ( Select Top (24*4) N=-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1 ) B
 Cross Apply ( values ( dateadd(MINUTE,N*15,convert(datetime,Date))  ) ) C(UTC_DateTime)
```

**Results**

```
UTC_Datetime            ID  Event1  Event2
2021-07-01 00:00:00.000 31  0       0
2021-07-01 00:15:00.000 31  0       0
2021-07-01 00:30:00.000 31  0       0
....
2021-07-01 02:30:00.000 31  1       0
2021-07-01 02:45:00.000 31  1       0
2021-07-01 03:00:00.000 31  1       0
2021-07-01 03:15:00.000 31  1       0
2021-07-01 03:30:00.000 31  1       1
2021-07-01 03:45:00.000 31  1       1
2021-07-01 04:00:00.000 31  1       1
```